# Ways of achieving inversion of control

Tags: design-patterns, inversion-of-control

What are the different ways we can achieve inversion of control ? I know we can achieve ioc through dependency injection. Could someone please list other ways and technique of achieving ioc?

Comment: tried searching it ?

Comment: Tried reading [a book](https://manning.com/seemann/)?

Comment: https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html; https://martinfowler.com/articles/dipInTheWild.html

Answer (score 2):

> I found
> https://www.sitepoint.com/three-design-patterns-that-use-inversion-of-control/
>
> **Implementing Inversion of Control**
>
> 1. IoC through Dependency Injection
> 2. IoC through the Observer Pattern
> 3. IoC through the Template Method Pattern

4. Events emitting
5. Callbacks
6. Middlewares

... another behavioral patterns which will allow you to change behaviour of object from outside.